# How to delete synchronized pictures?

Tags: sync, samsung-galaxy-nexus, delete

I've chosen *allow Google to synchronize information* from my email to my phone, but the result is not as interesting as it sounds! I see some pictures in the Gallery that I wouldn't have in my phone, unfortunately the delete option doesn't appear for these pictures. How to delete them? Is it possible to delete all synchronized information from Gmail to phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your google acct doesn't sync picasa photos. ..
Then go to **settings > application manager > all apps > gallery > clear data and cache**. Deletes the synced album.

Similarly you can clear all synchronised data from Gmail also.
In **settings->Accounts->Google->your account**, you can uncheck all options.
 So your Google details will not get synchronised...

Comment: Did this answer cleared your problem?

Comment: Yes it did, that's why I accepted it. Thank you.

Comment: Any more details needed? I'm asking because of bounty description.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up synchronization, it sets up sync with picasa and other services. You can go in to the Settings and accounts and unselect specific services, like picasa. That should remove the images from being synced to the phone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now Google photos sync is off but I still see those pictures in gallery!

Comment: once sync is off, you should be able to just delete them. They should not be deleted from picasa. I would test it with one image first though so you don't lose all the images if for some reason it does sync the delete.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your Google account and make sure you are checking off Google backup when you add in your account for the second time, this will work!

Comment: This is unnecessary, and removing the primary Google account is pretty much equivalent to a factory reset. Not many apps store their settings in Google's cloud, even if the option is enabled on your device.